# LED Driver with minimum input current and large LED current(peak)

Tags: led, driver

I am designing a LED driver.

Power source - 18V-42V (I can draw max of 6mA-7mA from source)
LED string - 4 series LEDs of 6 strings in parallel ( total 24 LEDs)

I need min of 200mA of peak/instantaneous current through LEDs with 20ms or 30ms ON every 1sec duration.

I am thinking to design like current sink method which will charge a big capacitor and I can draw current from it to drive LEDs.

Please let me know if anyone is having any different idea.

Comment: What forward voltage are the LEDs?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Work out the charge you need per pulse (dQ = amp-seconds = Coulombs) and decide the voltage sag you can tolerate on the capacitor to get its minimum value (C = dQ/dV).

Comment: @Andyaka Vf= 2.65V to 3.5V

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes I am doing the same thing, but problem is I can not offer big size cap (except super cap) on my expected board size.

Comment: Can you change power source to ensure it exceeds power drain? WHy ? 18V * 6mA = 48mW is inadequate

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I am thinking to use 18V or 20V zener in parallel to storage cap so that any input voltage between 18V to 42V will allow me Vz = 20V for LED drive ( in one string there are 4 LEDs, worst case LED drop will be 14V. I don't have option of changing power source or getting extra power, Its low power device.

Comment: Why so small? "(I can draw max of 6mA-7mA from source) "  You need 200mA yet if drop from 42V to 20V will waste 200mA*22V= 4.4W

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Its low power design board, for long life span. battery operated.

Comment: ok its very poorly defined for efficiency

Comment: @Micro Are you sure that the forward voltage for the LEDs are in your stated range when 200 mA is applied as a pulse? Also, if you need the battery to last longer, you almost certainly will be needing a switcher with a wide input range and a single output voltage. You don't want to waste energy. But designing one that has a limitation of input current will be "interesting."

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Um... I think 18 V * 6 mA is more like 108 mW. Just FYI.

Comment: @jonk  correct but still the design wants efficiency yet suggests the opposite way to implement it while there is no power conversion or energy spec.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I know. There's rarely enough specs to any of the questions here. It's like, "What specs? I don't have no stinking specs! Who needs specs? Just answer my question!" But one does have to muddle through. Where I do see specs, they are at least congruent. The pulse will be about 80 to 100 mJ. Once per second this is 80 to 100 mW. The input spec is, say 18 V at 6 mA to 7 mA and that is 100 mW to 120 mW or so. Not inconsistent. So, I can't complain there. It's just that this needs to be efficient and current limiting from the source.

Answer (score 0):

**Given:**

> Power source - 18V-42V (I can draw max of 6mA-7mA from source) LED string - 4 series LEDs of 6 strings in parallel ( total 24 LEDs)
>   I need min of 200mA of peak/instantaneous current through LEDs with 20ms or 30ms ON every 1sec duration. Vf= 2.65V to 3.5V

**Translation:**

**Input:**

Vi = 30V nom. ±12V (±40%)
Ii = 6mA to 7mA (nom.)
Pi = **180 to 210 mW (±40%) (nom.)** , **108mW (min.)**
Ri = 30V/6mA= 5kΩ (nom.), 18V/6mA= 3kΩ min. (est. for MPT)

**Output:**

**24 W. LEDs in Array , Pulsed at 1Hz rate 2~3% duty cycle**

Vf= 3.1 V ± 0.4V (depends on quality of parts and 
ratings)
If= 200 mA, 20ms min.  to  250 mA  (est.), 30ms max.

LED Array = 4S6P white (CCT, CRI, LPW unknown)
Vo = Vf * 4 + Io * Rs
Io = 6 * 200 mA (min.) (Rs=0 if buying binned parts  ±0.1V)
Po= Vo * Io = 12.4V (nom) * 1.2 A (min) ~ **15 W nom.**
Po avg.= Po * duty cycle , d.c. = 2~3%

- **Po avg. = 300 mW (nom)** = 15 W (nom) * 20ms/sec

  - d.c.= 2% min)

Output Power, Po avg exceeds input Pi: **Problem**.

**Conclusion**

- change power source or requirements or efficacy of LEDs